# Passing multiple vars in vue,js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm building a chat app, and in the cat vue component I have:

```
<template>
<div class="chat-app">
    <Conversation :contact="selectedContact" :messages="messages" @new="saveNewMessage"/>
    <ContactsList :contacts="contacts" @selected="startConversationWith"/>
</div>
```

then in the script part, in the methods array, I have:

```
saveNewMessage(message) {
            this.messages.push(message);
        },
```

Basically, there is an attribute in contact that I want to bring into the message to save it in message - the conversation_id.  Is there a way to get contact into saveNewMessage()?  I tried saveNewMessage(message, contact), but that didn't work.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to all the data properties in the your component methods:

```
saveNewMessage(message) {
  // access the selected contact
  this.selectedContact

  ...

  this.messages.push(message);
},
```

Comment: I tried to console.log(this.selectedContact) and I got undefined.

Comment: How are you assigning the selectedContact property?

Comment: I ate dinner and refreshed the page, and it worked!  Thanks!